# Using localstorage and checkboxes to customize a menu

Tags: jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I have a configuration page with ON/OFF checkboxes that I would like to control whether or not an item in the menu is hidden or shown.

Example of menu section:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li id="whyReplace"><a href="#">header</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><em>01</em> sub1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><em>02</em> sub2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><em>03</em> sub3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example of ON/OFF checkbox:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <div class="switch">
                 <input data-toggle-id="whyReplace" type="checkbox" checked />
            </div>
            Why should you replace?
         </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default, all are checked, as I would want all menu headers visible. From here I'd like to store any change to the checkbox in localstorage and if they decide to turn OFF a button, then .hide(); the corresponding header using matching data-toggle-id.

I was looking at this page for help, but it only helps me do half of what I need:

http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/using-html5-local-storage-and-jquery-to-persist-form-data-47

I must add that for this project, I am using Phonegap and xcode to publish it as an iPad app, so I have been testing in Safari.  These saved variables need to be persistent across all other pages too so the menu is customized based on which buttons were toggled on/off.

Using something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    for (var key in storage) {
        var menuhead = storage[key];
        if ($(menuhead).attr("checked") {
            $('li#' + menuhead).show();
        } else {
            $('li#' + menuhead).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

I need to know how to store the checkboxes in localstorage that I want to hide (turned off), loop through those stored variables and then .hide(); the menu item whose id matches the data-toggle-id.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you need to know, and what you already know how to do? Is your question on how to hide elements on page load based on localstorage variables?

Comment: @michael This is new stuff to me so if there's a better way I'm open to that.  Yes, I would like to hide elements in the navigation based localstorage variables and for it to be persistent.

Comment: I have one more question, how would I get this to work with bootstrap-switch on/off buttons?

http://www.larentis.eu/switch/

and

https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle that shows what I am dealing with:  http://jsfiddle.net/ukrb3/4/ It seems bootstrapSwitch isn't using the checked attribute and instead assigning the parent div a class of switch-on or switch-off

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if you already figured this out but see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VcGjx/
Note that it is using jQuery and running `onDomReady`

You can also use cookies instead of localstorage, then on the server side script set the hidden/checked attributes accordingly based on the cookie value. That way you will not get the flash of the elements before they are hidden that might happen with JavaScript.

Edit: to get this working with the bootstrap switch you need to use the change event instead of click, as it's the switch being clicked not the checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/ukrb3/5/

Comment: That is awesome and exactly what I was looking for, I can't wait to get this set up.  Thanks Michael! As soon as I get enough reputation I'll vote this up!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this, using an array,  that a friend help me figure out.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HrXp5/12/

The HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="list0">Widgets</li>
    <li id="list1">Gadgets</li>
</ul>

<h3>Toggle Menu's</h3>

<ul id="menu-toggles">
    <li>Widgets:
        <button type="button" id="toggle0" data-menuhead="list0" class="btn btn-primary menu-toggle" data-toggle="button">On</button>
    </li>
    <li>Gadgets:
        <button type="button" id="toggle1" data-menuhead="list1" class="btn btn-primary menu-toggle" data-toggle="button">On</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The JS:

```
var menu_storage_key = 'menu_items_off';
var menu_items_off = new Array();

if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    var storage = window.localStorage;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == 'On') {
            $(this).html('Off');
            if(menu_items_off.indexOf($(this).data('menuhead')) < 0) {
                menu_items_off.push($(this).data('menuhead'));
            }
        } else {
            $(this).html('On');
            $('#' + $(this).data('menuhead')).show();
            var new_array = new Array();
            if(menu_items_off.indexOf($(this).data('menuhead')) >= 0) {
                for (i=0; i < menu_items_off.length; i++) {
                    if(menu_items_off[i] != $(this).data('menuhead')) {
                        new_array.push(menu_items_off[i]);
                    }
                }
                menu_items_off = new_array;
            }
        }
        persist_data(menu_storage_key, menu_items_off);
        update_menu();
    });

    // running on document load
    load_menu_storage();
    update_menu();
    update_toggles();
});

function load_menu_storage() {
    // check to see if value exists
    if(storage.getItem(menu_storage_key) == null) {
        // if it doesn't exist, set it to empty array and return
        persist_data(menu_storage_key, new Array());
        return;
    }
    menu_items_off = get_data(menu_storage_key);
}

function update_menu() {
    // value exists, iterate through and set items off
    for (i=0; i < menu_items_off.length; i++) {
        $('#' + menu_items_off[i]).hide();
    } 
}

function update_toggles() {
    // value exists, iterate through and set items off
    for (i=0; i < menu_items_off.length; i++) {
        $('.menu-toggle').each(function() {
            if(menu_items_off[i] == $(this).attr('data-menuhead')) {
                $(this).html('Off');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
}

function persist_data(key, data) {
    storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}

function get_data(key) {
    return JSON.parse(storage.getItem(key));
}
```